How to fix overlapping faces and correct UV's?
I created an object with animation in Clo3d and i want to texture it in Substance Painter 3D. The problem is when i try to open it while checking the option "Use UV tiles workflow" it doesnt open and says i have overlapping faces. I checked my mesh and even using UV unwrap and Smart UV it still says i have overlapping faces. I realised my mesh has faces with diferent orientations, is there a way to fix it?

That mesh looks far too complicated for Blender to UV unwrap successfully. You mention two external programs which have nothing to do with Blender so you can't really expect it to do what you want.

I understand, thats why im asking for a solution because im a begginer so i dont really understand the implications of using different programs.

We can only help with problems you're encountering using Blender or its built-in addons. I'm afraid that anything else is off-topic here and as I said Blender won't be able to cope with that mesh which was created with an external program.

I just had closer look at your screenshots and see that the Substance Painter error message is about "faces spanning across multiple UDIMs"

If I'm guessing correctly this just means what it says, many UV faces (in your case triangles) have part of the triangle in one UDIM tile and the rest of the triangle in another UDIM tile and SP can't cope with that.
The fix should be easy enough.
Either you rescale and edit your UV islands so that all islands are confined to a single UV space (Square, UDIM tile) as they are in this screenshot:

Or you carefully spread the UV islands over more than one UV space (UDIM tile) ensuring that individual UV islands are wholly within the borders of one UDIM tile or another and not having a UV island partially in one and partially in another as you have at present.
In the example below I spread the UV islands into 2 UV spaces (2 UDIM tiles).
In the UV editor Create a New Image (Image > New), see screenshot below:

Next we create a second UV space (UDIM Tile) In this example we just create a second UDIM tile. These UDIM Tiles are automatically numbered from 1001 ...1002 ...1003 ...1004 etc.  see screenshot below: :

Now we can scale up the UV islands:

and then reposition the islands into the 2 UDIM tiles. Make sure that no individual islands is spread over the border between the 2 UDIM tiles.

TLDR: At the moment your UV islands are extending beyond the square UV space. Keep the UV islands safely within the borders of a single UV space or individual UV islands safely within the borders of a single UDIM tile. T
I'm hoping this now solves your issues :)

When i wrote the reply i had already adjusted the UV's so they were looking as the result you showed. The problem i mentioned is when i imported to Substance Painter 3D it reseted my UV's to the original for some reason. Tho recently, i managed to change some settings when importing and i was able to get the UV's differently but in a way that its all inside a tile and it works. But once again, another problem came, theres no Alembic option to export so i had to export has Obj(wavefront) in wich doesnt export the mesh with the animation.

Indeed you do have 3 overlapping UV islands. (Using the Blender file that you posted yesterday).
The 3 UV islands of the bodice's left side, back and Shoulder strap are overlapping the 3 UV islands of the right side, back and strap.
While it is possible to select 2 of these islands (side and strap) in the UV editor and move them so that they are not overlapping, the upper back part of the bodice won't allow that. trying to select 1 results in selecting both. So the following is a bit more complicated than it could have been.
Instead of selecting the problematic UV islands directly in the UV editor we are going to select the corresponding faces on the dress itself and then move the UV islands. But to do that we need to have UV seams on the dress. UV seams on the model are the borders of the UV islands in the UV editor.
Lets start:

In Edit mode select all of the dress. A key.
Go to the UV editor and select all the UV islands. A key.
Open the UV drop-down menu and choose the Seams from Islands option.
This will mark UV seams on the dress corresponding to the borders of the      UV islands.


The dress now marked with UV seams separating it into "panels" which corespond to individual UV islands :

Next we select the problematic "panels" on the dress which in turn will select the relevant UV islands in the UV space.

In the 3D viewport first enable the Face Select mode. Next hover your mouse over the bodice's left side panel and hit the L key.
The panel will now be selected. Repeat for the left back and left shoulder strap panels. When all 3 panels are selected go to the UV editor and you should find the 3 corresponding  UV islands selected.


All that is left to do now is to move these 3 UV islands into an empty space in the UV square.

When selecting all of the dress again we can see the 3 UV islands that were previously overlapped.

Not necessary but advisable : before exporting from Blender you should edit the UV islands within the UV space (square) so that you are wasting as little of the UV space as possible. doing this will result in a higher quality texture for your dress, more pixels per meter/inch. (a higher resolution texture=. something like in the screenshot below:


First of all, thank you so much for actually taking the time to analise the project and making a full explanation for me to understand, truly apreciate it. Sadly even tho i did it all, when i import it to Substance Painter 3D, the uv's gets reseted for some reason even tho i uncheck every box. I dont know if its because its connected to the Clo3d (Mesh sequence modifier)file but ill search further to see if theres anything i can do.
Thank you once again for the full explanation!
